# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre usar isin() con .any(), .any().any() y .all() con Pandas?

Tags: python, lista, pandas, dataframe

El problema es el siguiente, estoy intentando saber si los elementos de una lista, se encuentran en un dataframe. El dataframe son dos columnas y unas 3000 filas. Cualquier elemento de dicha lista puede aparecer indistintamente en una columna o la otra. He optado por esta solución:

```
data = pd.read_csv(files, header = 0, sep = ';').loc[:, [' 7Flight1', ' 18Flight2']]
if data.isin(flightsid).any().any():
    print ("Están")
else:
    print("No está")
```

He probado también:

```
data = pd.read_csv(files, header = 0, sep = ';').loc[:, [' 7Flight1', ' 18Flight2']]
if data.isin(flightsid).all().all():
    print ("Están")
else:
    print("No está") 

data = pd.read_csv(files, header = 0, sep = ';').loc[:, [' 7Flight1', ' 18Flight2']]
if data.isin(flightsid).all():
    print ("Están")
else:
    print("No está")

data = pd.read_csv(files, header = 0, sep = ';').loc[:, [' 7Flight1', ' 18Flight2']]
if data.isin(flightsid).any():
    print ("Están")
else:
    print("No está")
```

Dándome las dos últimas el error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

No estoy seguro de si he utilizado la mejor solución, ¿hubiera sido mejor utilizar merge o join? ¿he utilizado correctamente el .any() o el .all()?

Muchas gracias por cualquier comentario!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que todas esas funciones producen una serie o una matriz con valores de cierto o falso. Entiendo que quieres ver si cierta comparación sea cierta a través de todo el df. Aconsejo a que ataques el problema de otra manera. La lógica del análisis podría ser la siguiente:

(1) aplanar todos los datos a una lista singular
(2) convertir esta lista a un conjunto/set
(3) convertir la lista de vuelos a otro conjunto
(4) simplemente analizar si hay una intersección entre los dos conjuntos.

Esta metodología también resulta ser flexible y rápida si se trata de muchos datos.

```
print(data)
# Supongamos que los datos se vean así:
#    7Flight1  18Flight2
# 0      2498       7527
# 1      8756       8632
# 2      2503       6676
# 3      6673       6750
# 4      3386       6339
# 5      3570       3933

# Y supongamos que la lista de vuelos sea así:
flightsid_ls = [2498,8632]

# Incluye numpy:
import numpy as np

# Debes aplanar el dataframe convertido en una matriz así: 
df_values_ls = list(data.to_numpy().flatten())
# Por ejemplo, esta lista de datos aplanados se ve así:
# In [1]: df_values_ls
# Out[1]: [2498, 7527, 8756, 8632, 2503, 6676, 6673, 6750, 3386, 6339, 3570, 3933]

# Luego, puedes sacar provecho de las rutinas de conjuntos/sets de python 
# para ver si haya una 'intersección' entre los datos aplanados/flattened y tu lista de vuelos.

df_values_set = set( df_values_ls )

flightsid_set = set( flightsid_ls )

# Al hacer la siguiente comparación, te da flexibilidad:
intersection_ls = df_values_set.intersection(flightsid_set)

# Puedes simplemente medir el tamaño de esta lista, o hacer algo
# si es que uno o varios pero no todos los vuelos de la lista
# están entre los datos.

if len(intersection_ls) == 0:
    print("No están")
else:
    print("Se encuentran los siguientes vuelos:")
    print(intersection_ls)
```

Comment: muchas gracias! no se me había ocurrido algo así